# QTreeView: no children displayed when indentation level is 1

Tags: pyside, qtreeview

When I set the indentation level to 1 for a QTreeView, the view no longer requests the data for child items of the top level.   So I just end up with top level items.  The items have children, but no data is requested of the children

When indentation level is set to 0, the child items are requested and I get child items displayed and the top level items have the expanders to hide or show the children.

So what could be the problem with setting the indentation level to 1?

EDIT:  The problem was my assumption that an indentation level of 1 represented an indentation of one tree view column.  Actually it is the number of pixels to indent.  Low indentations cause the text to be displayed over the expansion widget, so it looks like there are no children. I had also assumed the default indentation level was 0, which is why I assumed it worked.  The default is 20.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a small code example for it?

Comment: While coming up with some sample code, I found the issue.  See the edit in the OP.

Comment: I'm happy you could solve the problem on your own. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my assumption that an indentation level of 1 represented an indentation of one tree view column. Actually it is the number of pixels to indent. Low indentations cause the text to be displayed over the expansion widget, so it looks like there are no children. The default indentation is 20.